# Write value on a specific row in SAS

Tags: sas

I want to write in a column the index of the row based condition.

I can write the last row index of a group.

| col1 | index |
| --- | --- |
| A | . |
| A | . |
| A | 3 |
| B | . |
| B | 5 |
| C | . |
| C | . |
| C | . |
| C | 9 |

I want to write in a new column row indexes based on `index` column.

| col1 | index | New column |
| --- | --- | --- |
| A | . | . |
| A | . | 2 |
| A | 3 | . |
| B | . | 4 |
| B | 5 | . |
| C | . | . |
| C | . | . |
| C | . | 8 |
| C | 9 | . |

```
data HAVE;
infile datalines;
input col1 $1.;
datalines;
A
A
A
B
B
C
C
C
C
;

data have2;
set have;
by col1;
if last.col1 then index=_n_;
run;
```

Comment: I do not understand why you would want to do such a thing.  Which makes it sound like an https://xyproblem.info/.  Can you explain what the overall problem you are trying to solve is and how being able to make this second extra variable will help?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Since your data are grouped by the ID, you could approach this as a look-ahead problem, to detect when the next ID changes (or next next). Something like:

```
data HAVE;
infile datalines;
input col1 $1.;
datalines;
A
A
A
B
B
C
C
C
C
;

options mergenoby=nowarn ;
data want ;
  merge 
   have 
   have(keep=col1 rename=(col1=_col1_lead1) firstobs=2)
   have(keep=col1 rename=(col1=_col1_lead2) firstobs=3)
  ;

  if      col1 ne _col1_lead1 then index =_n_ ;
  else if col1 ne _col1_lead2 then index2=_n_ ;

  drop _: ;
run ;
options mergenoby=error ;

proc print data=want ;
run ;
```

Returns:

```
Obs    col1    index    index2

 1      A        .         .
 2      A        .         2
 3      A        3         .
 4      B        .         4
 5      B        5         .
 6      C        .         .
 7      C        .         .
 8      C        .         8
 9      C        9         .
```

If you have an ID with only one record, this might not do what you want.  But I'm not sure what you would want in that case.

Answer (score 1):

Just do the same thing a second time.  You will have to add some extra logic.  The NOTSORTED option will let you treat INDEX as a BY variable so you can find the last observation in the set of observations with missing values of INDEX.

```
data want;
  set have2 ;
  by col1 index notsorted ;
  if last.index and missing(index) then new_index=_n_;
run;
```